# Trying to pop a UIAlert if my search predicate returns nil

Tags: core-data, uialertview, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I'm trying to pop an alert that says "No records found" if the user does a search and the predicate returns nil.

I tried this, but the alert never gets called. I just get an empty tableview.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    if (self.sBar.text != nil){

        NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] $SEARCH OR optionOne contains[cd] $SEARCH OR optionTwo contains[cd] $SEARCH"];
        NSDictionary *replace = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.sBar.text forKey:@"SEARCH"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:replace];

        [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    }

    [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];

    if (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects != nil) {

        //do nothing

    } else {

        //display alert
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"No records match." 
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();  // Fail
    }           

    [self.myTable reloadData];

    [sBar resignFirstResponder];  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ha! Got it...

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    if (self.sBar.text != nil) {

        NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] $SEARCH OR optionOne contains[cd] $SEARCH OR optionTwo contains[cd] $SEARCH"];
        NSDictionary *replace = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.sBar.text forKey:@"SEARCH"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [template predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:replace];

        [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    } 

    if ([[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] != 0)  {

        [self.myTable reloadData];
        [sBar resignFirstResponder];  

    }
    else {

        //display alert
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"No records match." 
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A predicate does not have a `-count`.  A predicate [is an expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29).  That's it.

You can ask the `NSFetchedResultsController` for its `-fetchedObjects` (which returns an array), and then ask that array for its `-count`, but you can only do this after you invoke `-performFetch:`.

Comment: ...added fetchedObjects count, but still nothing.

Comment: @RyeMAC3 did you do `performFetch:` first?